# How to Create an Aggregate Function?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do you create an **Aggregate Function** to get the **total sum of a column** for example?
I know this is built in as the `SUM()` function but i need to make other more complex functions and this seems like a good place to start.

- Is the use of cursor's necessary?
- The parameter definition is the sames as for normal functions?
- And what variable scope should i use?

I'm not concerned with speed or efficiency only with the most simple way to do it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You may want to read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-udf.html

Comment: Why not tell us a bit more about what you're after?

Comment: It is extremely rare that the most simple way to manipulate data is to create a compiled udf. I agree with @Strawberry, you should describe what you are really after and we can suggest solutions. The solution may indeed be a compiled udf, but it is extremely likely that we can suggest some alternative solution using native sql functions.

Comment: @strawberry i need to create several aggregate function for college but my professor only though us the basics, he translated [https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/](this) to our local language give it to us in a pdf.
I need to recreate max(), min(), avg(), and a function that manipulates dates.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner thank you. but this seems a bit to complicated I think we are supposed  to do it only with SQL. Is there no other way ? if not i will just use the built in fuctions and wrap them with a diferent name and some extra steps.

Comment: This is nothing that can be done with SQL only. But, yes, you can of course combine aggregation functions or combine aggregation functions with other expressions. `COUNT(*)` and `SUM(1)`do the same thing. `SUM(value) / COUNT(value)` is the same as `AVG(value)`, `SUM(CASE WHEN value = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` counts yesses, etc.

Comment: I don't think you can define aggregate functions using SQL, they can only be done as UDF: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-udf.html#udf-aggr-calling

Comment: Are you using mysql or mariadb? The latter can create aggregate functions in sql as well. Mariadb is a fork of mysql, but it is not mysql.